# CoreData Object is nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8, xcode6

I'm using CoreData in my app to load data into an UITableView. If I run this code snippet the app crashes:

```
let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
newManagedObject.setValue("Test String", forKey: "markedCell")
```

this is the part I use to loading the data into the tableView:

```
let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
var taskString:NSString
taskString = object.valueForKey("name") as String
cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("name") as? String

var request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"markedCell = %@", taskString)
    var results : [NSManagedObject] = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as [NSManagedObject]
    if (results.count > 0) {
        //Element exists
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    }
    else {
        //Doesn't exist
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }
```

Crash line: `taskString = object.valueForKey("name") as String`
Error message: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I just get this crash if I use the first code snipped above. If I don't use this code the app runs fine. I really don't know why it's crashing / some value is `nil`.

Hope you can help me. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Replace var taskString: NSString with

```
if let taskString = object.valueForKey("name") as? String {
    cell.textLabel!.text = taskString
    // rest of your code
}
```

Also your app crashes because object.valueForKey("name") is not a String ie there is no value returned.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html